# BitBucket pipeline shows npm: command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ssh, bitbucket-pipelines

After deploying code to my server using bit bucket scp pipe, I am using another pipeline to run a script to install node modules and start node server but the pipeline results as failed status and shows like

./server-run.sh: line 1: npm: command not found
./server-run.sh: line 2: pm2: command not found

following is my yml file

```html
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  custom:
    test:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
            - pipe: atlassian/scp-deploy:0.3.3
              variables:
                USER: $USER
                SERVER: $SERVER
                REMOTE_PATH: '/var/www/stockTest/server'
                LOCAL_PATH: 'server/*'
    server-start:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - ssh $USER@$SERVER "cd /var/www/stockTest/server && ./server-run.sh"
```

server-run.sh

```html
npm i
pm2 start server-start.js --name stockTest
```

Answer (score 2):

1> in your server terminal run echo $PATH

this will give below out put   /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.5.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

2> Now open nano /etc/environment and paste the path there like given below

```
 PATH="/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.5.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

This will surely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.
So I had these commands to my files :

```
whoami
which npm
```

Which output :

```
LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStart
Script - cicd/development/scripts/start_server.sh
[stdout]ec2-user
[stderr]which: no npm in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

So it can't find `npm` but not because it's not the right user, so I did a :

```
$ which npm
~/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/bin/npm
```

Then I understood that it was due to where npm was installed.
So I just download the binary and put it in `/usr/local/lib/nodejs`

And then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase pm2 is not installed,you have to install pm2 first.

**Try** Before executing pm2

#### npm i -g pm2

**or** you can give

#### npx pm2 start server-start.js --name stockTest

Comment: I already have pm2,npm and node.js in my server and able to run manually